# Any idea of how I can get the sum of the most recent invoices per customer compared to a specific amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, invoice

We use 3 tables in SQL Server, one for customer's transactions (custtrn), one for customer's details (customer), and one (cusfindata) that is holding the remaining amount that every customer has to pay.

What I need is to find the most recent invoices, but the sum of these invoices must not exceed the amount that they have to pay.

Some additional info I can give you are:

```
custtrn.cusid = customer.id
and cusfindata.cusid = customer.id
```

To be more specific and a bit easier: if I owe a company 1000€ and I do have some invoices from the company how I can find the most recent invoices that their sum is equal or less than 1000€

A sample of data could be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIvWq.jpg)

At this example, I need to retrieve from Dimitris invoice numbers 16,15,12 with a total of 90€ because the next one (No 11) exceeds the amount of 100.

Comment: Most people here want sample data etc as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: (A) Edit your title to summarize your specific technical issue. No one here cares about your customers and invoices; we care about a particular technical problem. (B) Your English is just fine, no need to apologize. But your Question is not clear. It could use some rewriting for clarity. I suggest you think it through a bit more.

Comment: This Question might be better served on the sister site, DBA Stack Exchange.

Comment: Good morning, I thank you for your advice, i will come up again with this. I edited the tilte allready

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query satisfy your requirements.

Test data:

```
drop table if exists Customer;
drop table if exists Cusfindata;
drop table if exists Custtrn;

create table Customer (
    id int identity,
    code int,
    name varchar(30)
);

create table Cusfindata (
    id int identity,
    custid int,
    amount numeric(10,0)
);

create table Custtrn (
    id int identity,
    invoicenumber int,
    custid int,
    amount numeric(10,0),
    invoicedate date
);

insert into Customer(code,name)
    values ( 100 , 'Dimitris' ), ( 102 , 'George' ), ( 104 , 'John' );

insert into Cusfindata( custid, amount)
    values ( 100, 100 ) , ( 102 , 50 ) , ( 104 , 80 );

insert into Custtrn(invoicenumber,custid,amount,invoicedate)
    values (  1 , 100 ,  50 , '20180701' ) , (  2 , 100 ,  30 , '20180708' ) , 
           (  3 , 102 ,  20 , '20180715' ) , (  4 , 102 ,  56 , '20180722' ) ,
           (  5 , 104 ,  54 , '20180729' ) , (  6 , 100 ,  80 , '20180805' ) ,
           (  7 , 104 , 150 , '20180812' ) , (  8 , 102 ,  20 , '20180819' ) ,
           (  9 , 102 ,  23 , '20180826' ) , ( 10 , 102 ,  60 , '20180902' ) ,
           ( 11 , 100 ,  40 , '20180909' ) , ( 12 , 100 ,  20 , '20180916' ) ,
           ( 13 , 104 ,  20 , '20180923' ) , ( 14 , 104 ,  30 , '20180930' ) ,
           ( 15 , 100 ,  60 , '20181007' ) , ( 16 , 100 ,  10 , '20181014' ) ;
```

Solution:

```
with my_summary as (
    select c.code,
           c.name,
           cf.amount as limit,
           ct.invoicedate, 
           ct.invoicenumber,
           ct.amount [invoice amount],
           SUM(ct.amount) over (partition by c.code order by ct.invoicedate desc,ct.invoicenumber desc) [total to pay]
    from Customer c 
        join Cusfindata cf on c.code = cf.custid
        join Custtrn ct on c.code = ct.custid
    -- exclude invoices with amount greater than limit 
    where ct.amount <= cf.amount 
) 
select s.* 
    from my_summary s
    where s.[total to pay] <= s.limit;
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jacek, I will give it a try and i will come back later today. It is quite a day today!

Comment: Jacek, i get an error "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled." This is a version issue asi have see so far (my version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64)   Sep  3 2014 04:11:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) )
I think that: "SUM(ct.amount) over (partition by c.code order by ct.invoicedate desc,ct.invoicenumber desc) [total to pay]" has something to do with it...